# Завідувач чи завідуючий?

Tags: вибір-слова, стилістика, дієприкметники

На сайті ["Онлайнкоректор"](http://onlinecorrector.com.ua/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%87/):

> Вживання дієприкметників активного стану з *-уч-*, *-юч-* **не рекомендовано** нормами сучасної української мови.
>
> Замініть *завідуючий (чим)* на варіант: *завідувач (чого)*, або перебудуйте речення, використавши дієслово *завідувати*.

Але у посібниках Євгенії Чак, зокрема [«Чи правильно ми говоримо?»](http://chak-chy-pravylno-my-hovorymo.wikidot.com/z#zaviduvach) і [«Складні випадки українського слововживання»](http://litmisto.org.ua/?p=21008):

> Завiдувач, завiдуючий (завiдувачка, завiдуюча). Обидва слова, звичайно,
> **не відрізняються один від одного** змiстом; обидвi форми поширенi в
> сучаснiй мовi, але не тотожнi вони своïми синтаксичними зв'язками в
> реченнi…

(Виділення напівжирним моє.)

Answer (score 3):

Все просто: **«не рекомендовано» — це не те саме, що «заборонено» чи «слова немає»**. Слово може існувати, але вважатися не найкращим за стилістикою, застарілим абощо.

Згідно з сучасним «Словником української мови» в 20 томах:

> [**ЗАВІ́ДУВАЧ**](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=28064&page=936), а, *ч[оловічий рід]*, *чого*. Той, хто завідує, керує яким-небудь виробництвом, науковим підрозділом, кабінетом і т. ін. <…>
>
> ---
>
> [**ЗАВІ́ДУВАЧКА**](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=28065&page=936), а, *ж[іночий рід]*, *чого*. Жін. до **заві́дувач**. <…>
>
> ---
>
> [**ЗАВІ́ДУЮЧИЙ**](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=28065&page=936), чого, *ч[оловічий рід]*, *чим*, рідко. Те саме, що **заві́дувач**. <…>

Зверніть увагу на примітку «рідко».