# Як правильно вживати "керівник" чи "керуючий"

Tags: вживання-слів, дієприкметники

Нещодавно потрапив у руки наказ ["Про затвердження Порядку призначення  та звільнення, а також функції та повноваження податкового **керуючого**"](http://zakon0.rada.gov.ua/laws/show/z1430-10). Але неодноразово чула, що вживати слово керуюючий неправильно. На підтвердження цього знайшла:
[Керівний, керівник, управитель і керуючий](http://onlinecorrector.com.ua/%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%96%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%96%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA-%D1%83%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C/). То, все-таки, особливо у офіційних документах, яке слово правильно вживати?

Comment: Related: https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/3118/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сучасний [Словник української мови](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=41479&page=1309) містить таку статтю:

> КЕРУ́ЮЧИЙ, а, е. 1. Який керує; керувальний.
>
> – Я, світлий пане, люблю й важу обряд і мову батьків, але признаю керуючу руку (Н. Королева)

На тому ж сайті [Оnline corrector](http://onlinecorrector.com.ua/%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%96%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%96%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA-%D1%83%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C/), про який Ви вже згадували, пишуть, що:

> Вживання дієприкметників активного стану з -уч-, -юч- не рекомендовано нормами сучасної української мови. Замініть керуючий на один з варіантів: керівний; керівник, управитель.

У статті [12 поширених помилок в українській мові](http://studway.com.ua/12-poshirenikh-pomilok/) подають інформацію на прикладі слова "миючий":

> Слово «миючий» з’явилося в українській мові внаслідок калькування російського «моющий». В академічних перекладних словниках вказано правильний український відповідник – «мийний».

Аналогічно і керуючий: від рос. управля**ющ**ий.

> Це лише одна з низки подібних кальок. Слід мати на увазі, що активні дієприкметники на -уч(ий), -юч(ий) (для прикладу, **керуючий**, мотивуючий, омолоджуючий) *не властиві сучасній літературній мові*, і від них варто триматися осторонь. Натомість правильно вживати українські відповідники: **керівний**, мотивувальний, омолоджувальний.

Таким чином у документах трапляються такі іменники, але все ж, я вважаю, що слід оминати іменники із суфіксами -уч-, -юч- і замінювати їх на питомі суфікси -льн-, -н-.

Comment: В такому разі, коли з'являться зміни до класифікатору професій, де чітко зазначена посада **керуючий**?